# Gitlab omnibus update error (8.0.1 to 8.0.2)

Tags: update, centos7, gitlab, failed

I have a fresh install Gitlab server on CentOS 7 server. And when i try to update `sudo yum install gitlab-ce` the package to the version 8.0.2 i have an error:

```
... truncated ...
gitlab-ce-8.0.2-ce.1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | 336 MB  00:00:39
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
gitlab preinstall: Backing up GitLab SQL database (excluding Git repositories, uploads)
rake aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/opt/gitlab/backups
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/database.rb:15:in `dump'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:66:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:backup:db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Dumping database ...
gitlab preinstall:
gitlab preinstall: Backup failed! If you want to skip this backup, run the following command and
gitlab preinstall: try again:
gitlab preinstall:
gitlab preinstall:   sudo touch /etc/gitlab/skip-auto-migrations
gitlab preinstall:
... truncated ...
```

Comment: The problem is due to a bug in 8.0.1 [issue] (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/831).

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple. You can create a backup dir `/var/opt/gitlab/backups` and set correct owner and group to it.

```
sudo mkdir /var/opt/gitlab/backups
sudo chown git:root /var/opt/gitlab/backups
```

After that run update.

```
sudo yum install gitlab-ce
```

**install** not update, see the [doc](https://about.gitlab.com/update/)